# Changing datetimepicker background color C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datetimepicker in my Windows form. This may sound like a silly question with a rather simple answer. However, I just can't find a solution to fit my purpose.

Question > Is there a way in which I can change the back colour of the datetimepicker in the form to a different colour other than the generic white?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `BackColor` property

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        myDateTimePicker1.BackColor = Color.Red

        myDateTimePicker2.BackColor = Color.Yellow

        myDateTimePicker3.BackColor = Color.Green

    End Sub

End Class
```

or Overrides `OnPaint` function

[msdn with more details](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a32fe2b-e415-457d-9ef6-ac5d3a059c5c/how-to-change-the-color-of-my-date-time-picker-and-make-a-validation-for-it?forum=vbgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`CalendarMonthBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.calendarmonthbackground?view=netcore-3.1) property to the color of your choice, but it depends on the theme as well.

Comment: This may not work if you've called `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` at the beginning of your program.